# How to make all lines equal thickness?

Tags: drawing

I have a 2d black and white hand-drawn artwork like a cat, cow, or ironbox. The lines are of various thicknesses, one line is 1mm, another is 3mm, another is 4mm. I want to make all the lines in my drawing equal in thickness. Is there any software or online tool available to achieve this? Though it is a raster image, I have the tools to convert it to a vector image. I not an expert in drawing or graphics designing.

[image]

Comment: I this hand drawn artwork? A raster image? A vector image? This is fairly impossible to answer without knowing the artwork's current format.

Comment: Yes, it is a hand-drawn artwork, but can be vectorized if there is a solution (for the above requirement) for the vectorized artworks only.

Comment: If you redraw it using vector software, you could simply select all the paths, and change the stroke width to the same width.  Any vector software could be used, such as Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, Affinity Designer, Inkscape (which is free), etc.

Comment: Those who downvote should state the reason so that we can correct our mistakes. Without that, there is no meaning in the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but those who do usually do so because the question is either unclear or because it shows a lack of research. In this case you have now added an image, which is helpful.  Have you done any research into vector drawing applications?  You seem to already know that making a vector will solve the problem. Auto tracing is possible using most vector software, however it will just trace the image as it appears, and won't help you make all the lines the same width. Some also have centre line tracing, but that also comes with issues. Better to redraw it manually.

Comment: The problem with automatic tracing such as Illustrator's Live Trace (stroke only -mode in your case) is lack of intelligence. Programs do not interpret line crossings right. You'll get unwanted twists if the lines do not meet perfectly at 90 degrees. There's special tools which are made for vectorizing CAD drawings or maps and with them the result can be less miserable if your drawing is simple enough and you have scanned it with resolution up to the task. Your attached drawing is far too blurry for succesful  tracing except by redrawing it manually - as others have already suggested.

Comment: (continued) You can purchase manual redrawing as vector. There are companies which sell it as service. Some of them say they bill nothing if you do not accept the result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried for a whole day, I have converted many raster images to vector images using online tools without issue, but, as far as the thickness is concerned, I could not find a way to make them equal, that's why I asked.

Comment: After the advice from @BillyKerr, I just downloaded Inkscape, I am trying to find a way to solve my problem.

Comment: I've now added an answer which might help you. Note that it's quite difficult to create a full tutorial here on GDSE, but there are good tutorials for Inkscape on youtube if you need more detailed instructions on how to use the tools.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your whole day failings have been caused by the fact that you have used tracing software which trace lines as filled areas, they do not extract them as curves. Illustrator's Live Trace in Stroke-only mode tries to do it and also Inkscape's Centerline Tracing. But they often make frustrating errors where lines meet. As said, manual redrawing at least works.

Comment: I catch your point, I am a programmer, I had no idea of such things. However, I will try that centerline tracing too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto tracing is possible using most vector software, however it will just trace the image as it appears, and won't help you make all the lines the same width. Some also have centre line tracing, but that also comes with its own set of inaccuracy problems. In reality there is no good way to automate the creation of vector images. There's no one to one conversion of raster images into vector images.

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to redraw the image manually using vector software, such as Inkscape (which is free), or Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, Affinity Designer, etc.

In the example below I used Inkscape.

Import the raster image into the software, lower its opacity. Then using the Pen tool (Bézier tool), redraw all the lines by tracing over the top of the raster image. You can also use the Ellipse tool to create circles.  When you have finished, delete the raster image.

You can then select all the paths, and change the stroke width using the stroke settings in the software, or change the stroke color, etc.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.